# firefox svg transform not working

Tags: firefox, svg, css-transforms

I am trying to use transform - translateX on the mask in in svg to animate it. But it doesnt work in firefox, however it works in chrome.

The javascript used to add styling

```
var a = document.getElementById("masker");
a.style.cssText += "-webkit-transform: translate(954px);"
a.style.cssText += "transform: translate(954px);"
```

Working fiddle for chrome http://jsfiddle.net/557UK/3/

Comment: Your fiddle seems to act identically in Firefox and Chrome, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky Sorry about that changed the fiddle link

Comment: Hmm.  This might be https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=779683